# How to remove empty html nodes with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to remove empty html nodes with HtmlAgilityPack. I want to remove all nodes like this:

```
<p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>
```

Here's what I'm trying but it's not working:

```
    static string RemoveEmptyParagraphs(string html)
    {
        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(html);
        foreach (HtmlNode eachNode in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p/span/text() = '&nbsp;'"))
            eachNode.Remove();
        html = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
        return html;
    }
```

Comment: Two things. First, if you want to delete any nodes, you can't use `foreach` but rather a backward `for` loop, because that is the only proper way to delete items from a list. Second, try changing the XPath string to `"//p/span[text() = '&nbsp;']"` or `"//p/span[contains(text() = '&nbsp;')]"` if you expect any spaces to appear in source HTML.

Comment: Thanks LightBulb, my xpath was a mess, that corrected the xpath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before loading the html with `document.LoadHtml(html);` you can do this:

```
document.LoadHtml(html.Replace("<p><span>&nbsp;</span></p>", ""));
```

Or have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579035/remove-all-empty-unnecessary-nodes-from-html):

```
static void RemoveEmptyNodes(HtmlNode containerNode)
{
  if (containerNode.Attributes.Count == 0 && !_notToRemove.Contains(containerNode.Name) && (containerNode.InnerText == null || containerNode.InnerText == string.Empty) )
  {
    containerNode.Remove();
  }
  else
  {
    for (int i = containerNode.ChildNodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        RemoveEmptyNodes(containerNode.ChildNodes[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Assa. In the end, I used a simple html.Replace and that did the trick.